# OpenLayers map initialised but not displaying

Tags: openlayers-2

I am using OpenLayers with Google maps. I have created my map object successfully - there are no errors raised and console.log(map) shows that it is indeed an OpenLayers class - but nothing is showing on screen. All I am seeing is a white rectangle.

Does anyone know what might cause this?

Any tips for finding the bug that is causing this?

With no errors or obvious problems I don't know where to begin. It should be working!

Comment: Can you please post a live link to the map - so we can debug using firebug and/or other developer tools. This is not a question that can be answered without more information from you.

Comment: I'm about to go home for the day but I'll try and post some code on monday. Any advice on how to go about debugging would be helpful. As I say the class appears to be set up correctly. What would you look for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could just be a css problem! Have you set correctly css properties of your map container?
Any code would be interesting if you want help from us.

Comment: but this is just an assumption...

Comment: Simo was right, it was a css issue. I had switched to a different css file which didn't have style a definition for div#map. Therefore the height and width properties weren't defined and without these the map doesn't display.